# Embed .avi video from file in Powerpoint 2010 (under Wine)

Tags: wine, microsoft-office, video-conversion

I've been using Office 2010 with Ubuntu 12.04.  I would like to embed an video (.avi format) into a .pptx file in Powerpoint.  It was originally a .mov file, so I used avconv to convert the .mov file to a .avi file:

```
avconv -i input.mov -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 ouput.avi
```

This works fine.  But, when I try and embed output.avi into Powerpoint 2010, I get the following error:

```
PowerPoint cannot insert a video from the selected file.  Verify the necessary codec for this media is installed, and try again.
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to install the necessary codecs (in Wine?) or embed the video in my PowerPoint?  Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a Microsoft issue, but do you have winetricks installed?

Comment: There are many codec packs available freely on the Internet. Installing one of them under WINE might help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert the file using a Windows Media codec, rather than h.264. I don't think Office can embed h.264 video by default. If you install the appropriate codec package under wine, though, it should start working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Could you point me toward an appropriate codec package that plays nice with MS Office?  It seems Windows Media Codecs 9 doesn't work with Wine (just tried and it gave me a "internal error" message).  Maybe WMC 8?

Comment: As a quick update, I tried installing

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use MS Office regularly, and I don't know which, if any, will play well with WINE. But Office 2010 probably needs the WMC 9 package to work best.

Comment: To finish my last update, I installed Windows Media Player 10 through Playonlinux (I installed MS Office through this program as well), and it said during installation that it was installing some codecs.  I just downloaded the test.wmv from this website: http://dougneubauer.com/mhcctest/ but it was still giving me the same error when I tried to embed the video file into Powerpoint 2010.  I wonder if other people have had the same issue?